# ¿Cómo Importar CSV a SQL server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Quiero importar una archivo CSV a mi base datos SQL Server 2008 R2. Digamos que el archivo original tiene 4 columnas:

estructura:

```
CREATE table
(
Numer INT,
Artitulo varchar (255),
Description varchar (255),
Fecha DATETIME,
)

+------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+  
|Numer | Artitulo                   |   Description   |    Fecha     |
+------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+  
|  1   | "Su mamá, es una ¡Señora!" |  "ñ!¡**,**<>\n" | 31/12/2018   |
+------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

Como verán la columna **artículo** dice el texto delimitado por comilla doble **(")**
***Su mamá, es una ¡Señora!*** y por otro la descripción contiene caracteres especiales que vemos son los siguientes (**á**,**¡**,**!** y la letra **ñ**) también en la columna 2 hay lo siguiente (**ñ**,**!**,**¡**,**,**,**<**,**>**,**\n**), creo son de tipo **ANSII (1252)** si no me equivoco al usar Navicat coloco **ANSII 1252** pero esos caracteres se transforman en el signo `?`, las preguntas que tengo son:

1) ¿Qué Encoding utilizo para que importe reconociendo esos caracteres desde Navicat o consulta SQL Server, obviamente delimitando el texto por doble comilla?

2) Para el caso de consulta en SQL Server, ¿Cómo importaría solo las tres primeras columnas con la consulta, reconociendo como delimitador de texto la doble comilla (")?

NOTA; Las comillas son imprescindibles por que son delimitadores de texto. Nótese hay una coma en Descripcion Puesta Adrede. y estoy usando SQL server 2008 r2

Intente Usar el que el amigo me dio abajo osea este:

```
CREATE TABLE #DataTemp
(
[Numer] varchar(255),
[Artitulo] varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
[Description] varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
[Fecha] varchar(255)
)
BULK INSERT #DataTemp
FROM 'C:\test.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
)
SELECT *
FROM #DataTemp
DROP TABLE #DataTemp
```

Para Hacerlo Rapido 1 agarre un bloc de notas edite el texto adentro y coloque

```
Numer,Artitulo,Description,Fecha
1,"Su mamá, es una ¡Señora!","ñ!¡,<>\n",31/12/2018
```

por ultimo cambie la extensión y agregue el nombre

**test.csv**

Pero mi resultado fue este:

```
+------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+  
|Numer | Artitulo | Description      |          Fecha          |
+------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+  
|   1  | "Su mamß | es una íSe±ora!" | "±!í,<>\n",31/12/2018   |
+------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Acá tienes un artículo que seguro te servirá: https://www.programandoamedianoche.com/2009/09/importacion-de-archivos-csv-con-el-comando-bulk-insert.
¡Suerte!

Answer (score 2):

> 1) ¿Qué Encoding utilizo para que importe reconociendo esos caracteres desde Navicat o consulta SQL Server?

Para el ENCODING debes hacer uso del [`COLLATE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-2017), por ejemplo:

```
SELECT '"Tostadora", "ñ!¡<>", 31-12-2018' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI;
```

Para conocer todos los tipos de codificación, puedes obtenerlos haciendo un `SELECT` a la función `fn_helpcollations()`:

```
SELECT name, description FROM fn_helpcollations()
```

Esto aplica para la versión de SQL Server 2008 o superior. Para el caso de Navicat, desconozco.

EL `COLLATE` puede aplicar para una columna en específico desde su creación, o en su caso, directamente en el `SELECT`.

> 2) Para el caso de consulta en SQL Server, ¿Cómo importaría solo las dos primeras columnas con la consulta?

El siguiente *query* hace la importación de tu archivo CSV, suponiendo que se encuentra en la ruta física "C:\Temp\CSV.csv" y que únicamente son 3 columnas a importar y aplicando un `COLLATE` a la columna B de tu archivo:

```
CREATE TABLE #DataTemp
(
     ColumnA VARCHAR(200)
    ,ColumnB VARCHAR(200) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    ,ColumnC VARCHAR(500)
)

BULK INSERT #DataTemp
FROM 'C:\Temp\CSV.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\Temp\CSVError.csv',
    TABLOCK
)

UPDATE #DataTemp
SET ColumnA = REPLACE(ColumnA, '"', ''),
    ColumnB = REPLACE(ColumnB, '"', '')

SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC FROM #DataTemp

DROP TABLE #DataTemp
```

El resultado de la importación sería el siguiente:

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
| ColumnA   | ColumnB | ColumnC    |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| Tostadora | +¦!-í<> | 31-12-2018 |
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

Nota: es importante hacer el `DROP TABLE #DataTemp` ya que la tabla temporal se almacena en tempdb, la idea es no ir dejando basuta en las tablas de sistema. De igual manera he aplicado un `UPDATE` a la columna A y B, esto es para que almacenen sin las comillas.

Comment: Hermano pero necesito excluir la columna c de la importacion

Comment: Y por sierto ahora es que me llama la atencion como creastes la colunma con los simbolos de + y -

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez En la importación no estoy seguro que se pueda excluir alguna columna, los signos de + y - se leen directamente del CSV

Comment: me sale este error

Comment: Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 58
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 5 (ItemModel).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 58
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 5 (ItemModel).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 58
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 12, column 5 (ItemModel).

Comment: yo me referia a los simbolos de + y - de stackoverflow.com que no se colocarlos en mis preguntas jejeje

Comment: OK si no puedo escluirlos esta Exelente, no importa yo hare un INSERT table SELECT  Excluidas FROM Table ahora el problema es cual es mi error?

Comment: por favor verifica caracteres especiales

Comment: Feliz año amigazo, y como delimita texto? necesito dellimitar texto con la (")

Comment: por cierto el remplace No lo requiero pues es necesario para delimitar el texto en las dos primeras columnas, lo segundo sigo con el mismo problema de la pregunta 1 que no se reconocen los acentos (á,é,í,ó,ú) al insertarse en la tabla.

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez si requieres delimitar el texto por las comillas entonces pierde el sentido totalmente el texto que pones de ejemplo. Sugiero que pongas datos mas acercados a los reales y ver qué tipo de información estás intentando ingresar

Comment: solo un pequeño detallazo las comillas no las pongo yo, ya vienen asi de un CSV con miles de registros delimitados por comillas